# how can i create an event "mouseover" on tag inside a svg document (called with the object tag )

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg image with some rect element inside, all identify by ID's.
I insert my svg like that :

```
<object id="svgObject" type="image/svg+xml" data="img/svg/monSvg.svg"></object>
```

So, for access to rect elements inside I need to use this code :

```
document.getElementById("svgObject").addEventListener("load",function(){

    var svgObject = document.getElementById("svgObject");
    var svgDoc = svgObject.contentDocument;
    var svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("monID");
    svgItem.style.display ="inline" ;   
    svgItem.style.fill = "red";
    svgItem.style.strokeWidth = "0";

   });
```

So this code works. But I want add a mouse over events on my "svgItem" and a tried with addEventListner, onmouseover etc... But it doesn't work... My event can't access in the Object tag document...

Someone have the solution for this problem ?

Thanks for your help.

Romain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you _can_ add event listeners to svg elements. Can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: onmouseevent works fine with object tag, could you post what you did?

Comment: This is the event that don't work : svgItem.addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
            alert("test");
        });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, my first guess was that you can not target individual SVG elements in an `<object>`, but I stand corrected. At least in Firefox (Developer Editor), Opera (Developer Editor) and Safari (9.0.2).

Steps to reproduce:

HTML/JS

```
<script>
    function onoff(elm) {
        elm.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
            elm.style.fill = '#f90';
        });
        elm.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
            elm.style.fill = '';
        });
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
        var doc = document.querySelector('#sample'),
            svg = doc.contentDocument || doc.getSVGDocument(),
            path = svg.querySelectorAll('path'),
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < path.length; ++i) {
            onoff(path[i]);
        }
    });
</script>
```

And [the SVG I used](https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/beacon.svg):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <g fill="#F00" stroke="#3b5998" stroke-width="4">
    <path d="M28,6h44v16l-22,21l-22-21z" fill="#6d84b4"/>
    <path d="M28,95h44v-16l-22-21l-22,21z" fill="#6d84b4"/>
    <path d="M6,30v42h15l21-21l-21-21z" fill="#afbfde"/>
    <path d="M95,30v42h-15l-21-21l21-21z" fill="#afbfde"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Now, as I would normally would try to run this from the filesystem directly, it will not work, both files *must* be served from the [same origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) which has to be a webserver, otherwise the SVG will load, but you *do not get to access it using script*.

That is just one of the caveats, and not the thoughest one to deal with.
I personally don't like the idea of accessing the contents of `<object>` as document on its own, as it is cumbersome and your mileage may vary based on the browsers you need to support. I'd just embed the `<svg>` into the HTML and have the benefits of using pure CSS to deal with hover states.

In which case you'd only had to add a simple rule

```
path:hover {
  fill: '#f90';
}
```

---

In your question you have the following line

```
svgItem.style.display = "inline" ;
```

SVG elements don't have the concept of `display`-flow, although there is some kind of flow going on you usually need to specify exactly where and how you want your elements to be drawn.

---

Finally, you may want to know [why I used both `.contentDocument` and `.getSVGDocument()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Scripting).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your very good answers ! It works perfectly now.